# On the Dirac Mass Type Functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

The question comes from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4111829/the-sequence-of-left-f-n-x-right-satisfying-lim-n-to-infty).

Let me rewrite part of the question:

Let $(f_{n})$ be a sequence of real-valued continuous functions on $[-1,1]$ such that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n}\int_{-1}^{1}f_{n}(x)dx=1,
\end{align*}
and that $f_{n}\rightarrow 0$ uniformly on $[-1,-\delta]\cup[\delta,1]$ for any fixed $\delta\in(0,1)$. Prove that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n}\int_{-1}^{1}f_{n}(x)g(x)dx=g(0)
\end{align*}
for any continuous real-valued function $g$ on $[-1,1]$.

I can only prove this under the assumption that $f_{n}$ being nonnegative on a neighborhood of $0$.

**What I guess is the following:**

I think it is true that $f_{n}$ is nonnegative on a neighborhood of $0$ for sufficiently large $n$, but I couldn't justify it.

The tricky part is the following.

For any $\delta\in(0,1)$, one can show that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n}\int_{-\delta}^{\delta}f_{n}(x)dx=1.
\end{align*}
Then there is a corresponding $N_{\delta}$ such that
\begin{align}
\int_{-\delta}^{\delta}f_{n}(x)dx>\dfrac{1}{2},~~~~n\geq N_{\delta}.\tag 1
\end{align}
I am thinking of using the Integral Mean Value Theorem, that is,
\begin{align*}
f_{n}(0)=\lim_{\delta\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{1}{2\delta}\int_{-\delta}^{\delta}f_{n}(x)dx.\tag 2
\end{align*}
But this leads to some technical difficulty. Note that in $(1)$, $n$ is running with $\delta$ fixed. While in $(2)$, $\delta$ is running with $n$ fixed, so I cannot really use Integral Mean Value Theorem in such a way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not true without assuming that $$\sup_n \|f_n\|_{L^1}< \infty$$ Try with $f_n(x)=\frac1{ C_n} e^{-\pi n^2 x^2}$ where $C_n=\int_{-1}^1 e^{-\pi n^2 x^2}dx$ (very close to $1/n$)
then $f_n+f_n'$ satisfies your hypothesis as well and you'll have that for $g \in C^1$ $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{-1}^1 (f_n(x)+f_n'(x))g(x)dx$$ $$=
\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{-1}^1 f_n(x)g(x)dx-\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{-1}^1 f_n(x)g'(x)dx=
g(0)-g'(0)$$

---

When assuming $\sup_n \|f_n\|_{L^1}< \infty$ it is true because taking $\delta_n\to 0$ such that $\int_{|x|>\delta_n} |f_n(x)|dx \to 0$ you'll have

$$\int_{-1}^1 f_n(x)g(x)dx = \int_{-\delta_n}^{\delta_n} f_n(x)g(x) dx+o(1)$$ $$=
\int_{-\delta_n}^{\delta_n} f_n(x)(g(0)+o(1)) dx+o(1)=g(0)(1+o(1))+o(\|f_n\|_{L^1})+o(1)=g(0)+o(1) $$

Comment: Okay, you gave a counterexample to the original question. But your $f_{n}+f_{n}'$ is not nonnegative on a neighborhood though.

Comment: @user284331 I added a proof when $\|f_n\|_{L^1}$ is bounded, which includes the non-negative case.

Comment: If a sequence of real continuous
 functions $\left \{ f_{n} \right \}$  defined on $\left[-1, 1 \right]$  satisfying the following conditions

  $$(1). \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{-1}^{1} f_{n}(x)dx=1;$$
  $$(2). \text{For any fixed } \delta \in \left(0, 1 \right)  , f_{n}\rightarrow 0 \text{ uniformly on } [-1,-\delta]\cup[\delta,1].$$ Are there a sufficiently large integer $N_{0}$ and sufficiently small positive number $\delta$, such that for any $n> N_{0}$, $f_{n}(x)$ are non-negative (resp. non-positive) on $[-\delta,\delta] ?$

Comment: @Elliot No there is an example in my answer

Comment: That's a pure stroke of genius .Why didn't I think of that !? ^__^  +1

Comment: @Elliot Because you are not used to approximate distributions (in particular $\delta'$) by sequences of smooth functions? The keyword is "mollifier"